# How to properly call JsonResult method in controller from view model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

From the oddity in my question, I suspect I'm not going in the right direction.

Supposed I have a view that has a paginated list among several other items. On first load, the list is loaded with the first page of the list (this is where I'm attempting to call my `JsonResult` method in the controller from the model).

```
public class FooListViewModel
{
    public FooListViewModel()
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime later = DateTime.Today.AddDays(5);

        // Here I need to make call to my JsonResult method 
        // in the controller to populate fooItems
    }

    public IEnumerable<FooItem> fooItems { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> dates { get; private set; }

}
```

In controller

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetItems(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    var fooItems = domainServices.Foo.GetAllFooItems();

    // Add predicates to filter between start and end dates.

    return Json(fooItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

On each page button click, it will reload ONLY the list with another call to the `JsonResult` method in the controller via AJAX, but this has already been done.

Comment: Rather than trying to describe what your code is doing, you will get better help if you can post a small complete example that reproduces the problem.  As it stands right now, I'm not sure what your question / problem is.

Comment: Fair enough. I added some code samples, but my question is in the title.

Comment: Ah. is there a reason you just don't call whatever your button click calls when the page first loads from javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to just simulate the button click on the client when the page just loads, then you only have one routine to do all the getting data, inserting into page and correctly formatting it.

Otherwise, create a GetData function that your controller routine (Index?) calls and your GetJSON routine calls to get whatever data you need.  The index method will stick this in the model to pass to the view, and the GetJSON routine just returns the result as json.

Sample code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
    model.data = GetData();
    return View(model);
}

public JsonResult GetJson(DateTime startDate,DateTime endDate)
{
    var result=GetData(startDate,endDate);
    return Json(result);
}

private IEnumerable<MyData> GetData(DateTime startDate=null,DateTime endDate=null)
{
    return something;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. My problem that I'm struggling with is in the model. I want to call JsonResult method *in* the model to parse for the initial load.

Comment: Updated answer now that I understand the question better.

Comment: That's a good point, Robert. Pretty obvious, too. I think this should be how I'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be calling action methods in any way other than via a HTTP request (since what you get back should he a HTTP response). This is, in a sense, like asking your server-side code to send a request to a page, which is all backwards.

If you have logic that you need in both in your controller and in your model constructor, you should probably be abstracting this logic from your presentation layer, exposing it in your business layer and just consuming it in both places:

```
public class FooProvider
{
    public List<Foo> GetFilteredFoos (/* whatever you need */)
    {
        // filter and return foos
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetItems(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    var fooItems = domainServices.Foo.GetFilteredFoos(/* some params */);
    return Json(fooItems);
}
```

Model:

```
public FooListViewModel()
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime later = DateTime.Today.AddDays(5);

    var ds = DomainServices();
    fooItems = ds.Foo.GetFilteredFoos(/* some params */);
}
```

Here, I assume that `DomainServices.Foo` is an instance of a class called `FooProvider`.

Having said this, however, I would avoid having this kind of login in your view model at all, where possible. Why not simply make the call in the controller when you first initialize the model?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = FooListViewModel();
    model.fooItems = ds.Foo.GetFilteredFoos(/* things */);
    return View(model);
}
```

Then, update via AJAX as normal.

Comment: Ok so this is a similar conclusion I came to, but should my domain services be exposed in the model? or is this the proper way to do it?

Comment: Generally, you would make this call in your controller after calling the model's constructor, but if it is something that has to occur every time a new model is initialized, there is no reason why you shouldn't allow your model to consume your services in this way. If you are worried about creating too tight a coupling between your presentation layer and your domain layer, perhaps you could pass your controller's `DomainServices` instance to the model's costructor via an interface?

Comment: Having said that, I would be tempted simply to make this call in the constructor on the initial GET request and then populate it with AJAX from then on.